# 2 and more UNIDIRECTIONAL relationship (onetoone)

Tags: java, entity, one-to-one

I have a question.

I have 3 entities: `member`, `contact`, `fine`

Member to contact (one to one unidirectional)
Member to fine (one to one unidirectional)

In the member entity class I've declared

```
@OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST})
   private ContactEntity contact;
```

when i try to run my app, everything is ok.

but when i try to add in fine

```
@OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST})
   private FineEntity fine;
```

there is error.

I try searching online and change it to CascadeType.ALL the error still exists.

Am I declaring it the correct way?

Comment: What kind of error? could you post your stacktraces.

Comment: javax.ejb.EJBException: nested exception is: java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
        java.rmi.RemoteException: Transaction aborted; nested exception is: javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction marked for rollback.; nested exception is: 
        javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction marked for rollback.